# MS-Access 2003 - Expression in a Text Box on a form

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba, expression

just wondering when using an expression on a form in a text box, to return a value from a table, can the expression have multiple tables in the expression to return the value?

the tables are linked and I can return the value in a query, so I figured that Access would be able to do it with this method as well????

`=DSum("[tblMain]![Revenue]","tblMain","[tblMain]![Quarter]=3 AND [tblMain]![Region]='NorthEast'" AND [tblOffice]![Location]='NewYork'")`

this is the expression that I entered into my text box, without the reference to the 2nd table it works fine, but once I had it, I get the flickering error message in the text box (just as on a report)......

I know this method is probably used more in reports than forms, but I am novice, and trying to come up with a dashboard solution that returns lots of facts quickly per department. I am using this in the "Control Source" field of the data tab of the properties window, not VB. Mainly because I do not know how to get it to work with VB.

Thanks for the help as always!

Comment: How is tblMain and tblOffice related? Is there any key in common between tblMain and tblOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot refer to more than one table or query in a domain aggregate function. As grazird says, how are these tables related? Let us say it is on tblMain ID, you can build a query called, say, qryMainOffice, the SQL (SQL View, Query Design window) would look something like:

```
SELECT [tblMain].[Revenue],[tblMain]![Quarter],[tblMain]![Region],
       [tblOffice]![Location]
FROM tblMain 
INNER JOIN tblOffice 
ON tblMain.ID = tblOffice.MainID
```

DSum would then be (remove line break):

```
=NZ(DSum("[Revenue]","qryMainOffice",
 "[Quarter]=3 AND [Region]='NorthEast' AND [Location]='NewYork'"),"Not found")
```

You could also use a recordset or query in VBA to return the value.

**EDIT re COMMENT**

To use the above in VBA, you either need to add parameters or use a string:

```
''Reference: Microsoft DAO 3.x Object Library
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL as String

Set db= CurrentDB

strSQL = "SELECT Sum(t.[Revenue]) As TotalNY" _
       & "FROM tblMain t " _
       & "INNER JOIN tblOffice o " _
       & "ON t.ID = o.MainID " _
       & "WHERE t.[Quarter]=3 AND t.[Region]='NorthEast' " _
       & "AND o.[Location]='NewYork' " _

 '' I have use aliases for simplicity, t-tblMain, o-tblOffice
 '' If you wish to reference a control, use the value, like so: 
 '' & " AND [Location]='" & Me.txtCity & "'"
 '' Dates should be formated to year, month, day
 '' For joins, see http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset strSQL

 If Not rs.EOF Then
    Me.txtAnswer = rs!TotNY
 Else
    Me.txtAnswer = "N/A"
 End If
```

You can also use different queries to return several results that can be shown with a list box or a subform:

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 5 o.[Location]," _
       & "Sum(t.[Revenue]) AS TotRevenue" _
       & "FROM tblMain t " _
       & "INNER JOIN tblOffice o " _
       & "ON t.ID = o.MainID " _
       & "WHERE t.[Quarter]=3 AND t.[Region]='NorthEast' " _
       & "GROUP BY o.[Location]"
```

The above would return revenue for quarter 3 for all locations in NorthEast region. If you want the top values of each group, you are looking at a more complicated query, which I will leave for now.

Comment: thanks! what about top nth queries where I would want to pick the actual record being displayed? So I have these top 10 figures, and I want to put a text box on a form to show the result of those. for each record I have a text box, how can I choose the actual record I want per text box? (i.e. textbox1 = first record, text box2=second record...etc of the returned recordset from the query)

Comment: Why does your previous question not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185327/ms-access-2003-creating-a-dashboard-return-values-to-a-form/1188084#1188084

Comment: sorry, I just am not quite sure what you are saying there...I am sure your right, it just may be a little over my novice head!!

would that be a sqlStr in VBA? 

this is what happens when you help a rookie!! :/

Comment: :) A little VBA can be very helpful. If you build an SQL string, you can do a lot with it, such as using it for a Control or Record Source. You also have a lot more control of the WHERE statement.

Comment: thanks! what else do I need in the vba to be able to use this. I figured out how write the sql in vb, but i cannot seem to figure out how to return the value.

for exampe if I built a query with the query builder, then run it, it shows a dataset with the returned values.

i cannot seem to get this to happen with the vba. so with the above, what in vba designates this to a certain text box's expression. what connects the vb to the expression. thanks for helping!

Comment: sorry i did not mean your exact example because I can see exactly what happens above, i meant if I were to make the query vba instead of sql in the query builder.

Answer (score 1):

How are these tables related?  Can you describe the relationship and any primary/foreign keys?

Also, referencing the table name is not necessary in the first parameter of this function (since it is already taken care of in the second one).

For example, your code could be:

=DSum("Revenue","tblMain","Quarter=3 AND Region='NorthEast'" AND [tblOffice]![Location]='NewYork'")

Just trying to save you some keystrokes and increase its readability. :)

Comment: oh thanks that helps actually because I write a lot of these. I actaully got it solved. Thanks!